# creation of container using docker-compose deletes another container that is already running

Tags: image, docker, docker-compose, containers

I am trying to start 2 separate containers using the `docker-compose` command based on 2 different images.

One image (work) is based on code worked on in "development". A second image (cons) image is created by code that is currently at the "consolidation" level.

## When starting the first container, all seems to go OK.

[image]

Details of above image are here:

**WORK DIRECTORY: ~/apps/django.work/extraction/docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres-work           
  web:
    build: .
    image: apostx-cc-backoffice-work        
    container_name: cc-backoffice-work      
    command: python3 backendworkproj/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "7350:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

**EXECUTION:~/apps/django.work./extraction$ docker-compose up --no-deps -d web**

```
Creating network "extraction_default" with the default driver
Creating cc-backoffice-work ...
Creating cc-backoffice-work ... done
```

**EXECUTION:~/apps/django.work/extraction$ docker container ls**

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
39185f36941a        apostx-cc-backoffice-work   "python3 backendwo..."   8 seconds ago       Up 7 seconds        0.0.0.0:7350->8000/tcp   cc-backoffice-work
dede5cb1966a        jarkt/docker-remote-api     "/bin/sh -c 'socat..."   2 days ago          Up 2 days           0.0.0.0:3080->2375/tcp   dock_user_display_remote
```

## But, when I work with the second directory to compile and start a different image, some strange things start to happen:

[image]

Again, more details are below:

**CONS DIRECTORY: ~/apps/django.cons/extraction/docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres-cons         
  web:
    build: .
    image: apostx-cc-backoffice-cons      
    container_name: cc-backoffice-cons    
    command: python3 backendworkproj/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "7450:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

**EXECUTION:~/apps/django.cons/extraction$ docker-compose up --no-deps -d web**

```
Recreating cc-backoffice-work ...
Recreating cc-backoffice-work
Recreating cc-backoffice-work ... done
```

**EXECUTION:~/apps/django.cons/extraction$ docker container ls**

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
f942f84e567a        apostx-cc-backoffice-cons   "python3 backendwo..."   7 seconds ago       Up 6 seconds        0.0.0.0:7450->8000/tcp   cc-backoffice-cons
dede5cb1966a        jarkt/docker-remote-api     "/bin/sh -c 'socat..."   2 days ago          Up 2 days           0.0.0.0:3080->2375/tcp   dock_user_display_remote
```

## Question

Why is the first container being supplanted when I start the second one? If it is due to some kind of caching issue, how can one re-initialize/clean/clear out the cache before running `docker-compose` for a second time? Am I missing something here?

TIA

## Update - I did the following:

> 1. got rid of old containers by using "docker container rm -f "

-

> 2. started the "work" (i.e. development) container

**execute:~/apps/django.work.ccbo.thecontractors.club/extraction$ docker-compose --verbose up --no-deps -d web >& the_results_are_here**

**execute:~/apps/django.work.ccbo.thecontractors.club/extraction$ docker container ls**

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
61d2e9ccbc28        apostx-cc-backoffice-work   "python3 backendwo..."   4 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        0.0.0.0:7350->8000/tcp   work-cc-backoffice
dede5cb1966a        jarkt/docker-remote-api     "/bin/sh -c 'socat..."   3 days ago          Up 3 days           0.0.0.0:3080->2375/tcp   dock_user_display_remote
9b4b8b462fcb        wmaker-test-officework      "catalina.sh run"        11 days ago         Up 11 days          0.0.0.0:7700->8080/tcp   testBackOfficeWork.2017.10.30.04.20.01
ad5fd0592a07        wmaker-locl-officework      "catalina.sh run"        11 days ago         Up 11 days          0.0.0.0:7500->8080/tcp   loclBackOfficeWork.2017.10.30.04.20.01
7bc9d7f94828        wmaker-cons-officework      "catalina.sh run"        11 days ago         Up 11 days          0.0.0.0:7600->8080/tcp   consBackOfficeWork.2017.10.30.04.20.01
```

> 3. seeing that it looks OK, started the container for "cons" (consolidation)

**execute:~/apps/django.cons.ccbo.thecontractors.club/extraction$ docker-compose --verbose up --no-deps -d web >& the_results_are_here**

**execute:~/apps/django.cons.ccbo.thecontractors.club/extraction$ docker container ls**

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
0fb24fc45877        apostx-cc-backoffice-cons   "python backendwor..."   5 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        0.0.0.0:7450->8010/tcp   cons-cc-backoffices
dede5cb1966a        jarkt/docker-remote-api     "/bin/sh -c 'socat..."   3 days ago          Up 3 days           0.0.0.0:3080->2375/tcp   dock_user_display_remote
9b4b8b462fcb        wmaker-test-officework      "catalina.sh run"        11 days ago         Up 11 days          0.0.0.0:7700->8080/tcp   testBackOfficeWork.2017.10.30.04.20.01
ad5fd0592a07        wmaker-locl-officework      "catalina.sh run"        11 days ago         Up 11 days          0.0.0.0:7500->8080/tcp   loclBackOfficeWork.2017.10.30.04.20.01
7bc9d7f94828        wmaker-cons-officework      "catalina.sh run"        11 days ago         Up 11 days          0.0.0.0:7600->8080/tcp   consBackOfficeWork.2017.10.30.04.20.01
```

> 4. Again, the name: work-cc-backoffice has been supplanted by name: cons-cc-backoffices  - work-cc-backoffice is totally gone now.

-

> 5. Looked at the file the_results_are_here (in the second run) to see if anything can be found

```
[... snip ...]

compose.cli.command.get_client: docker-compose version 1.17.1, build 6d101fb
docker-py version: 2.5.1
CPython version: 2.7.13
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
compose.cli.command.get_client: Docker base_url: http+docker://localunixsocket
compose.cli.command.get_client: Docker version: KernelVersion=4.4.0-72-generic, Arch=amd64, BuildTime=2017-09-26T22:40:56.000000000+00:00, ApiVersion=1.32, Version=17.09.0-ce, MinAPIVersion=1.12, GitCommit=afdb6d4, Os=linux, GoVersion=go1.8.3
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker info <- ()
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker info -> {u'Architecture': u'x86_64',

[... snip ...]

compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_network <- (u'extraction_default')
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_network -> {u'Attachable': True,
 u'ConfigFrom': {u'Network': u''},
 u'ConfigOnly': False,
 u'Containers': {u'61d2e9ccbc28bb2aba918dc24b5f19a3f68a06b9502ec1b98e83dd947d75d1be': {u'EndpointID': u'e19696ccf258a6cdcfcce41d91d5b3ebcb5fffbce4257e3480ced48a3d7dcc5c',
                                                                                       u'IPv4Address': u'172.20.0.2/16',
                                                                                       u'IPv6Address': u'',
                                                                                       u'MacAddress': u'02:42:ac:14:00:02',
                                                                                       u'Name': u'work-cc-backoffice'}},
 u'Created': u'2017-11-10T09:56:22.709914332Z',

 u'Driver': u'bridge',
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=False, filters={u'label': [u'com.docker.compose.project=extraction', u'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 1 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- (u'61d2e9ccbc28bb2aba918dc24b5f19a3f68a06b9502ec1b98e83dd947d75d1be')
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {u'AppArmorProfile': u'docker-default',
 u'Args': [u'backendworkproj/manage.py', u'runserver', u'0.0.0.0:8000'],
 u'Config': {u'AttachStderr': False,
             u'AttachStdin': False,
             u'AttachStdout': False,
             u'Cmd': [u'python3',
                      u'backendworkproj/manage.py',
                      u'runserver',
                      u'0.0.0.0:8000'],
             u'Domainname': u'',
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=True, filters={u'label': [u'com.docker.compose.project=extraction', u'com.docker.compose.service=web', u'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 1 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- (u'61d2e9ccbc28bb2aba918dc24b5f19a3f68a06b9502ec1b98e83dd947d75d1be')
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {u'AppArmorProfile': u'docker-default',
```

> To me, it looks like the program is trying to do some initialization
>   by looking for a container that is already up and running(?) See pic.
>   below. How can one change this behavior

[image]

Comment: That seems odd! Any difference if you provide the docker-compose file as an argument like [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/)? Also pop in --verbose after docker-compose to see if anything jumps out at you.

Comment: @ mikeyjk - thanks for the input. I made some updates to the message. Is there anyway around this problem? Am I missing something? Tia

Comment: No worries. I wonder if you give each service a unique name, re run composer build, whether the issue still occurs. I'll try and replicate it today if no-one can work it out.

Comment: Hey @mikeyjk - that did the trick. I never thought about taking that approach :-|  I changed the service name from "web" to "web_work", "web_cons", "web_test", "web_prod"  (did the same for the DB stuff) and all was working. Thanks again for the tip!

Comment: No worries at all, glad it worked. I'll try and dig up the single line of documentation that probably explains this haha.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from @mikeyjk resolved the issue.

> No worries. I wonder if you give each service a unique name, re run
>   composer build, whether the issue still occurs. I'll try and replicate
>   it today if no-one can work it out